# Style in CSS when dynamically created in JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created this button within my JS function such that every time someone clicks my HTML button, it will output the text input:

```
$("#new-item").on('click', function() {
    var text = $('#task').val();    
    $('#list').prepend("<li>" + text + " " + "<button class='started'>Started</button>" + "</li>" + "</br>");
});
```

The idea came from [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6wbsujL5/97/).

Now I want to style the button in my CSS file but my code isn't altering anything.

Here's what I did in my css:

```
.started {font-size: 10px;}
```

HTML Code:

```
</head>
<body>
        <header>
            <a href="https://trello.com"></a>
        </header>

        <section>

            <input type="text" id="task">

            <button id="new-item"> Add a card </button>

            <div class="column" id="to-do">
                <h1> To Do </h1>
                <li id="list"></li>
            </div>

            <div class="column" id="doing">
                <h1> Doing </h1>
            </div>

        </section>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="_js/main.js"> </script>
</body>
```

Comment: what's a snippet? sorry new to this whole thing

Comment: Somewhere that we can test your codes. The thing is, it worked for me, so I think there are other things that is the real problem

Comment: You shouldn't use `#started`, because it's an ID and it should be unique. Use `.started` and `class='started'` instead.

Comment: Ok I changed based on the above comments and added my HTML code

Comment: Conflict when using '#' ids, use '.' class instead.

Comment: Man, that code above you updated is completely working. http://jsfiddle.net/6wbsujL5/97/

Comment: Hmmm I was trying to show my complete code with HTML, CSS, and JS but when I was running it in the snippet it's not working but it's working on my local console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works fine for me. The only thing I changed is instead of `id="started"`, I used `class="started"`, because `id` should always be unique

```js
$("#new-item").on('click', function() {
  var text = $('#task').val();

  $('#list').prepend("<li>" + text + " <button class='started'>Started</button></li></br>");
});
```

```css
.started {
  font-size: 10px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <a href="https://trello.com">Trello</a>
</header>

<section>

  <input type="text" id="task">

  <button id="new-item"> Add a card </button>

  <div class="column" id="to-do">
    <h1> To Do </h1>
    <li id="list"></li>
  </div>

  <div class="column" id="doing">
    <h1> Doing </h1>
  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: If it helped you *(well, I don't really know which part helped you)*, tick the check button below the up-vote down-vote button to mark this as answer.

Answer (score 0):

To change your button style use this code

```
button.started {font-size: 10px;}
```